# Monotonicity at a Point - How is it checked?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

As far as I know, for a given function f(x) if we have to check monotonicity at a point x = a, we check which ones of the following inequalities (or equalities) are being satisfied -

1. f(a + h) > f(a) > f(a - h)
2. f(a + h) < f(a) < f(a - h)
3. f(a + h) > f(a) = f(a - h)
4. f(a + h) = f(a) > f(a - h)
5. f(a + h) < f(a) = f(a - h)
6. f(a + h) = f(a) < f(a - h)
7. f(a + h) > f(a) < f(a - h)
8. f(a + h) < f(a) > f(a - h)
9. f(a + h) = f(a) = f(a - h) 
   *for small h*

My confusion lies here. **Does the value of the function's derivative at x=a have anything to do with its monotonicity at x=a?**

For example, let's discuss the monotonicity of y = x² at x = 0. 
Using the definitions stated above, it is easy to observe that 
f(0+h) > f(0) and f(0-h) > f(0) **but** f'(0) = 0.

Could someone please help clear the confusion, and tell what's the real definition for monotonicity at a point and also why the two above methods don't agree with each other?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does tell you the monotonicity when the derivative is non-zero. When it is zero, it's a critical point, so we can't determine if it's monotone or not.

In your example, you're totally correct, it's inconclusive since for $f(x) = x^2$, $f'(0) = 0$, and it's not monotone. However $g(x) = x^3$, $g'(0) = 0$ but it's monotone.

So the idea is that for a continuous $f(x)$ that's differentiable on an interval containing $a$ (please correct me if this is not the exact condition), $f'(a) \neq 0 \implies $ $f(x)$ monotone around $x=a$

Comment: If f'(a) = 0, can something certainly be said about monotonicity? (Given that f'(x) is not zero over an interval)

Comment: @schrodinger_16 by only knowing that $f'(a) = 0$, no. A good way of putting it is from [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotonicFunction.html): A function is monotonic if its first derivative (which need not be continuous) does not change sign.

Comment: Hmm, so would you call x³ monotonic at x = 0? The derivative does change sign, right? Positive → Zero → Positive?

Comment: Also, more specifically, I'm interested in knowing if y = x³ is monotonically *increasing* at x = 0?

Comment: @schrodinger_16 ah, good questions. We don't usually say that going from positive to zero or vice versa is changing signs, since zero has no sign. $x^3$ monotonically increasing. It satisfies your definition that $f(a-h) < f(a) < f(a+h)$, for $h > 0$ actually across its entire domain.

Comment: I suppose the key here is that when $f'(a) = 0$, we don't know, just like how we don't know if $f(a)$ is a min or max if its derivative is 0. We need more information about its *second derivative*. But if $f'(a) \neq 0$, then we have a conclusive answer.

Comment: Ah, got it now. Thanks!

Comment: A function can have positive derivative and not be increasing on any interval. Such a function must have discontinuous derivative (due to MVT), so it might not arise in an intro analysis class.

Comment: @ElliotG ah yes, that’s why I specified differentiability on an interval is needed to make the claim. Is that sufficient?

Comment: You need "continuously differentiable." I.e., the derivative exists and is continuous. (It is pretty counterintuitive that derivatives can be discontinuous, but you have to be wary of all pathological constructions in analysis.)

Answer (score 0):

We only talk about monotonicity on an interval — not a point.

So the answer to your question is: they are not necessarily related. If the function is infinitely differentiable (such as polynomials, exponentials, etc), then $f'(x_0)>0$ implies that $f'$ is positive *on an interval* containing $0$. Then the mean value theorem shows you that $f$ is increasing on that interval.

However, [this site](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-whose-derivative-at-0-is-one-but-which-is-not-increasing-near-0/) gives a function which has positive derivative at $0$ but which is not increasing on any interval containing $0$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in short, yes. The derivatives of the function does tell us about the monotonicity of the function. But when  $f'(x)=0$, its a critical point (i.e. the function is not differentiable or the slope is zero)

In such cases, we check the inequality around the point.
In this case for $f(x)=x^2$, $f'(0)=0$

Here $f(a-h) > f(a) < f(a+h)$,  since its neither increasing nor decreasing at the given point, we can say that its the point of extrema. This can also be verified from the graph of $y=x^2$.

So we can't state that the function is monotonus in its natural domain.
But if we change the domain to $x ∈ (0,∞)$ or $x ∈ (-∞,0)$, we can say the function is monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing respectively.

Hope it helps.